# Rest Api: data shows on console but html table shows undefined

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, rest

My post data is being displayed on the console. But the html table shows undefined

The image below shows the problem.
[image]

My Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Loading all posts
    var loadposts=function(){
            
            $.ajax({
            
            url:"http://localhost:12091/api/post/",
            crossdomain: true,
            method:"GET",
            complete:function(xmlhttp,status){
                if(xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    
                    var data=xmlhttp.responseJSON;
                    $("#msg").html(data[0]);
                    console.log(data[0]);
                    
                    
                        var str='';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            str += "<tr>";
                            str += "<td>"+data[i].UserId+"</td>";
                            str += "<td>"+data[i].PostId+"</td>";
                            str += "<td>"+data[i].Post1+"</td>";
                            str += "<td><button class='btn btn-danger' onclick=\"deletepost("+data[i].PostId+")\">Delete</button></td>";
                            str += "<td><button class='btn btn-info' onclick=\"editpost()\">Edit</button></td>";
                            str += "</tr>";
                        }
                        $("#show__posts tbody").html(str);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#msg").html(xmlhttp.status+":"+xmlhttp.statusText);
                }
        }
        });
    }
    loadposts();
});
```

The html table:

```
<div class="container">
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <table class="table table-striped" border="1" id="show__posts" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>Post Id</th>
                <th>Post</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Probably irrelevant but i'm using asp.net web api in the backend

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have a `.length` property for objects. If you want to work it out, you have to use `Object.keys(data).length` instead.